# How to train out of dojo during summer?

Tags: training, judo, self-training

Dojos are no longer available in summer. Can I stay 2 months without training?
Should I organize training on the beach with my team even if sand is not as convenient as a mat?
Indeed, sand is harder than a mat when you fall down and less stable to move fast (ankle injuries).
I'd like to avoid losing all I capitalised during this year. Of course, I could train in a fitness room to gain muscle, but I fear to decrease speed.
If someone had an experience to cope with long no training period i would appreciate.

Comment: You won't gain enough muscle in a couple of months to have any physical impact on speed, particularly if you also do mobility drills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no problem in training on the beach as long as the sand is dry, clean (no rubbish), relatively plain (no bumpiness) and fine (it *adapts* better to the impact, same reason why it should be dry).

1. It might be slightly harder than a mat, but it's far from dangerous. It might even improve ukemi by 'punishing' bad posture or lack of tension. Modern mats are very forgiving.
2. Training on sand stresses small muscles from the feet up to the core. This is not to be confused with danger; it actually improves stability in the long run, as you will train muscles that simply are not needed on plain, relatively stable ground like mats. It will improve your stance. If you slip on sand, you were unstable in this movement, which could also have been punished by an attentive, fast opponent.
3. Grappling strength can be improved by grabbing into the sand and squeezing the fist repeatedly.
4. Training on the beach in summer has another big advantage: cooling down is near and easy ;)

Comment: Thank's Philip, you conviced me. I'm going to train on the beach early the morning before tourists invade and regard us as crazzy people ;)

Answer (score 1):

Keep **fit**, **strong**, **flexible**, **visualize**.

Go for a daily run, do some push-ups, sit-ups and stretching. Keep your cardio engine going.

Keep your mind on your training by practicing visualization of your techniques and self-defense. This is the vital part as it helps with consolidating on what you know so far. Do this during a run

Before you know it, you're back at training feeling ready for the next challenge.